# Relative dimension and linear independence in $\Omega_{X/S} \otimes_{\mathcal O_{X,x}} \kappa(x)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X = \operatorname{Spec} A \rightarrow S = \operatorname{Spec} R$ be a morphism of schemes.  Assume $A = R[t_1, ... , t_n]/\mathfrak a$, for $\mathfrak a = (g_1, ... , g_t)$ a finitely generated ideal.  Let $x = \mathfrak P \in X$ be a prime of $R[\underline{t}] = R[t_1, ... , t_n]$, lying over $s=\mathfrak p \in S$.

We say $f$ is unramified at $x$ if the images of $dg_1, ... , dg_t \in \Omega_{R[\underline{t}]/R}$ generate $\Omega_{R[\underline{t}]/R} \otimes_{R[\underline{t}]} \kappa(\mathfrak P)$.  Equivalently, $\mathfrak PA_{\mathfrak P}$ is generated by $\mathfrak p$, and $\kappa(\mathfrak P)$ is a finite separable extension of $\kappa(\mathfrak p)$.

If $f$ is unramified at $x$, then the stalk of the fiber $f^{-1}(s)$ at $x$ is exactly $\kappa(\mathfrak P)$, and in particular, $f$ has relative dimension zero at $x$.

The book I'm reading, *Neron Models*, makes a more general claim which I'm trying to understand.  I know that $\Omega_{R[\underline{t}]/R}$ is a free $R[\underline{t}]$-module of rank $n$.

[image]

Condition (e) is the statement "Equivalently, $\mathfrak PA_{\mathfrak P}$ is generated..."

I'm not sure how to begin verifying the claim about relative dimension.  I thought I should start with the case where $\mathfrak a = (g_2, ... , g_n)$, and assuming the images of $dg_2, ... , dg_n$ are linearly independent.  I know that $\Omega_{R[\underline{t}]/R} \otimes_{R[\underline{t}]} \kappa(\mathfrak P)$ has dimension $n$ as a vector space over $\kappa(\mathfrak P)$.  Perhaps I can let $g_1$ be an element of $R[\underline{t}]$ such that the image of $dg_1$ forms a basis with $dg_2, ... , dg_n$, and let $\mathfrak a' = (g_1, ... , g_n)$.

Comment: I accidentally posted this on overflow instead of stackexchange, which is a more appropriate place for this question.  I've now put the same question on stack (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154351/relative-dimension-and-linear-independence-in-omega-x-s-otimes-mathcal-o)